# Am I enumerating my IEnumerable<T> n times?

Tags: c#, linq, enumeration, deferred-execution

I am *fairly* comfortable with LINQ in c#, but am lost on whether or not my foreach loop is causing excessive enumeration.

Assuming the following code snippet is run,

```
var listOfStuff = new List<CustomObject>
{
    new CustomObject { Id = 1, Cost = 20M },
    new CustomObject { Id = 2, Cost = 11M },
    new CustomObject { Id = 3, Cost = 3.75M },
    new CustomObject { Id = 4, Cost = 50.99M }
};
var newObjects = listOfStuff.Select(thing =>
    new AnotherObject { Id = x.ID, NegaCost = decimal.Negate(x.Cost) });

foreach (var i in n) // a list of objects with a length of n
{
   var match = newObjects.Where(PreDefinedPredicate);
   i.DoSomethingWith(match);
}
```

is a new `AnotherObject` instance being created n times or am i misunderstanding the concept of multiple enumerations?

Comment: Assuming that `DoSomethingWith` iterates your query then yes on each loop through the `foreach` you will creat a new set of `AnotherObject`s to filter.  To avoid that you could do `ToList` before entering the `foreach`.

Comment: Yes, you are instantiating the object multiple times but only when you enumerate the collection so if you need to hydrate it use `ToList` - ah beaten to the punch :(

Comment: It's enumerated in another method performed on the `i` object, but i'm assuming the same will occur.
Thanks!

Comment: Surely this is easy enough to test?

Comment: Probably, but in my defense i'm new here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what do you do with `match` in `i.DoSomethingWith`, but if you are iterating it in there, then yes.

You can always check you assumption introducing some side-effect like `Console.WriteLine`:

```
var newObjects = listOfStuff.Select(x =>
    {
         Console.WriteLine($"Here with id: {x.Id}"); // SIDEEFFECT
         return new AnotherObject { Id = x.ID, NegaCost = decimal.Negate(x.Cost) };
    });

foreach (var i in n) // a list of objects with a length of n
{
   var match = newObjects.Where(PreDefinedPredicate);
   i.DoSomethingWith(match);
}
```